# Spring - Prototype scope guarantees thread safe?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, rest, jax-rs

I have already tried to find on internet, but I not found the answer that I want. 
I'm developing a rest service in JAX-RS (jersey implementation).

Inside my rest-service I have declared a client that is used to call backend-service.

How I have declared this client is the point of my question.

```
@Path("/restService")
public class RestServiceImpl implements RestService {

    @Autowired
    private BackEndClient backEndClient;

    //below there are GET, POST requests...
```

in the **application-context.xml**

```
<bean id="backEndClient" class="it.business.backend.client.BackEndClient" scope="prototype"> </bean>
```

How you can see, I have manage the bean instantiation with Spring. And in the xml side this bean is prototype. *So, for each request, RestServiceImpl and backEndClient are instantiated*.

Is this sufficient to guarantee thread safety, or not? 
What could be the critical issues?

Comment: Is BackEndClient thread safe? Spring can manage the threads for you but the important parts of BackEndClient that need protection are up to you

Comment: @efekctive, BackEndClient is not developed from us. We just have the interface that exposes the methods. The implementation is hidden. Suppose it is thread safe, declaring it like prototype is correct?

Comment: Is RestService a controller?

Comment: @efekctive, If you mean spring-controller: no, it's not. Like you can see from the code, there is not a Controller or RestController annotation above it. It's a simple JAX-RS service. **Update**: sorry, do you meant RestService, not RestServiceImpl? RestService is a classic interface in java.

Comment: Either way, it is serving a path. I don't believe the logic mapping the paths will need more than one instance of it. The point is that I believe the @Autowire will be called just once, so prototype or singleton will be the same

Comment: @efekctive, why they should be the same? With scope="prototype" the BackEndClient constructor is called for each request of RestService. With default scope, singleton, that constructor is called once.

Comment: The **effect** is the same. But this is a digression. Yes. the prototype should be more than enough. And even a singleton should do the trick

Comment: @efekctive, ok. But can you explain me please why the effect should be the same?

Comment: Imagine that there is only one end-point. the container mapping path to instance will create **one** instance of RestServiceImpl. Then @Autowire will be used **only** once. Thus prototype or singleton work the same due to demand

Comment: The prototype scope does not improve the thread safety here. As @efekctive explained, `RestServiceImpl` is only instantiated once, and in turn `BackEndClient` once as well, regardless of the bean scope. If `BackEndClient` is thread safe, you don't need the explicit prototype scope. If it's not, the scope won't help and you'll have to create an instance of `BackEndClient` within the request processing methods as needed.

Answer (score 0):

So to summarize, the scope in this case does not have a say in the thread safety.

The cotaniner will likely create only one instance of RestServiceImpl mapped to @Path. So @Autowired will be used only once thus rendering the prototype scope useless. The real issue will be if the third party backend is thread safe

Answer (score 0):

What thread issues are you concerned about? You've not indicated which component here is not thread safe. If they are all thread safe there is no need to worry making them `prototype` scope.

If, say, the client is NOT thread safe, it is not enough to simply mark the client as `prototype` scope.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-sing-prot-interaction

> When you use singleton-scoped beans with dependencies on prototype
>   beans, be aware that dependencies are resolved at instantiation time.
>   Thus if you dependency-inject a prototype-scoped bean into a
>   singleton-scoped bean, a new prototype bean is instantiated and then
>   dependency-injected into the singleton bean. The prototype instance is
>   the sole instance that is ever supplied to the singleton-scoped bean.
>
> However, suppose you want the singleton-scoped bean to acquire a new
>   instance of the prototype-scoped bean repeatedly at runtime. You
>   cannot dependency-inject a prototype-scoped bean into your singleton
>   bean, because that injection occurs only once, when the Spring
>   container is instantiating the singleton bean and resolving and
>   injecting its dependencies. If you need a new instance of a prototype
>   bean at runtime more than once, see [Section 7.4.6, “Method injection”](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-method-injection)